# Central limit theorem in R, exercise question from a random number dataset

Tags: r, standard-deviation, central-limit-theorem

I am currently trying to solve the following exercise in R with a random dataset:

1. Calculate the means and variances
   of the rows of the following simulated data set, and plot the distributions
   of means and variances using `hist()` and `boxplot()` functions.

```
set.seed(100)

#sample data matrix from normal distribution
gset=rnorm(600,mean=200,sd=70)
data=matrix(gset,ncol=6)
```

2. calculate the standard deviation of the
   distribution of the means using the `sd()` function. Compare that to the expected
   standard error obtained from the central limit theorem keeping in mind the
   population parameters were  $\sigma=70$ and $n=6$.

I am not sure what is exactly meant by this, 'the standard deviation of the distribution of means', isn't that the central limit theorem SEM? What **2** functions are asked for? My go on this was the following

```
SEM <- sd(data)/sqrt(600)
```

And further, i thought that n=600 and not 6?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You are probably expected to look at the row means of your $100\times 6$ matrix, with each of those $100$ values (the number of rows) being the mean of a sample with $n=6$ (the number of columns)

Comment: Are you sure the description of the task is correct? What is the $n=6$ “population parameter”?

Comment: Ah, so I am expected to calculate the means and the variances of the rows, so  I would use the rowMeans and rowVars function, right? And then compare the results of:
sd(rowMeans) with sd(data)/sqrt(6) right?

Comment: Yes you are expected to use `rowMeans()`.  But I think you are then expected to look at the standard deviation of those means as an estimate of the standard error of the mean so compare `sd(rowMeans(data))` with `70/sqrt(6)`.  You would hope `sd(data)/sqrt(6)` would also be close

Comment: Thanks a lot Henry, got it now!